# Cross Origin calls from curl working without needed headers

Tags: rest, http, curl, cross-domain

I am invoking one of my APIs using curl as follows(cross origin).

```
curl -H "Origin: foo.com" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -v https://localhost:9443/api/v10/configs -k
```

I have not set the necessary cross origin headers in the server side. But the API call works. Why is that?

on server side API class, in the options call I am only setting the Allow header.

```
 @OPTIONS
    public Response options() {
        return Response.ok().header(HttpHeaders.ALLOW, "GET").build();
    }
```

The following headers are not set.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
```

Answer (score 3):

CORS is a mechanism to enable cross domain requests but in the browser using AJAX. If you use curl you can do what you want ;-)

So in your case (using curl), you try to execute the request outside a browser. So you are free to do what you want! With curl, the request will be always executed and you will see the exchanged headers for example. This can be something helpful to see if you have the expected headers for CORS...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to get a better understanding of how it works, and the main purpose it serves.

Just some into snippet

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.  For example, `XMLHttpRequest` follows the same-origin policy. So, a web application using `XMLHttpRequest` could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow `XMLHttpRequest` to make cross-domain requests.
>
> The W3C Web Applications Working Group recommends the new Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism. CORS gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers. Modern browsers use CORS in an API container - such as `XMLHttpRequest` - to mitigate risks of cross-origin HTTP requests.

So CORS was introduced to allow for cross-domain access (from scripts) in browsers. How it works is that when a a request is made that requires cross-domain authorization, the browser first makes an OPTIONS ("preflight") request to look for the access response headers. If they are there, then it make the initial request. Otherwise there is a request error.

As an aside, I would avoid implementing CORS support in resource methods. I would instead use a filter mechanism so all requests are handled in the filter, instead of having to implement an `@OPTIONS` method for all endpoints.